# How to use checkbox for 2 queries for population from DataGridView in vb.net

Tags: sql, vb.net, checkbox, datagridview

How to use checkbox for 2 queries for population from DataGridView in vb.net?.

I tried with the code below the population in the datagridview became empty please recommend because maybe my code implementation has something wrong.

```
Private Sub PopulateDataGridView()
    Try
        dt = New DataTable
        If CheckBox1.Checked = False Then
            Dim query = "select ITM,ITC,QOH,PRS,PRSOBBRT,PRSOBNET,SHI,FILENAME1,FILENAME2,FILENAME3,FILENAME4,FILENAME5,FILENAME6,SUBFOLDERP FROM IFG WHERE QOH > 0 AND GDN = 'A.04.01.002.001'"
        Else
            If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
                Dim query = "select ITM,ITC,QOH,PRS,PRSOBBRT,PRSOBNET,SHI,FILENAME1,FILENAME2,FILENAME3,FILENAME4,FILENAME5,FILENAME6,SUBFOLDERP FROM IFG WHERE QOH < 0 AND GDN = 'A.04.01.002.001'"
                Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, cn.ToString)
                    adapter.Fill(dt)
                End Using
                Me.GridControl1.DataSource = dt
                Me.GridControl1.Refresh()
                GridView1.Columns("SUBFOLDERP").Visible = False
                GridView1.Columns("FILENAME1").Visible = False
                GridView1.Columns("FILENAME2").Visible = False
                GridView1.Columns("FILENAME3").Visible = False
                GridView1.Columns("FILENAME4").Visible = False
                GridView1.Columns("FILENAME5").Visible = False
                GridView1.Columns("FILENAME6").Visible = False
            End If
        End If
    Catch myerror As OleDbException
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
    Finally
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: You're not executing your query when the checkbox is false.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer , so what kind of solution so that I can use or switch with checkbox with 2 queries

Comment: The only bit that should be inside the conditional logic is the part that's different, which is just the SQL code. Everything else is the same regardless of the CheckBox so do everything else once outside the condition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve.

You can try something like this:

```
   Dim query As String
   If CheckBox1.Checked Then
       query = "first query"
   Else
       query = "second query"
   End If
   'execute query
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I tried your answer the result of population in DataGridView remains empty

Comment: Does your query return rows? Have you checked it directly against the database?

Comment: so it only shows the columns of the datagridview in the absence of its data . ` Try
            dt = New DataTable
            If CheckBox1.Checked Then   Dim query = "select query 1"   Else Dim query = "select query 2"  Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, cn.ToString) adapter.Fill(dt)  End Using Me.GridControl1.DataSource = dt End If ` my code example looks like this

Comment: Only showing the columns means that the query returned no rows. Check the query directly against the database.

Comment: ,Sorry for late reply `Only showing the columns means that the query returned no row` yes right and I've tried direct queries without checkboxes running normally

Comment: Before this line `Me.GridControl1.DataSource = dt` what is the value of `dt.Rows.Count` in each case?

Comment: I've tried your code successfully population to DataGridView but the checkbox doesn't work or it has no effect to the second query

Comment: `Before this line Me.GridControl1.DataSource = dt what is the value of dt.Rows.Count in each case?` You mean variable "dt" I use  `Private WithEvents dt As New DataTable`

Comment: I don't mean variable "dt". I mean debug your code and see what the value of dt.Rows.Count is when the checkbox is true, and again when the checkbox is false. Your query isn't returning rows. Debug and check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub PopulateDataGridView()
        Try
            dt = New DataTable
            dim query as string = ""

            If CheckBox1.Checked Then
                query = "select ITM,ITC,QOH,PRS,PRSOBBRT,PRSOBNET,SHI,FILENAME1,FILENAME2,FILENAME3,FILENAME4,FILENAME5,FILENAME6,SUBFOLDERP FROM IFG WHERE QOH < 0 AND GDN = 'A.04.01.002.001'"
            Else
                Dim query = "select ITM,ITC,QOH,PRS,PRSOBBRT,PRSOBNET,SHI,FILENAME1,FILENAME2,FILENAME3,FILENAME4,FILENAME5,FILENAME6,SUBFOLDERP FROM IFG WHERE QOH > 0 AND GDN = 'A.04.01.002.001'"
            End If

            Using adapter As New OleDbDataAdapter(query, cn.ToString)
                adapter.Fill(dt)
            End Using

            Me.GridControl1.DataSource = dt
            Me.GridControl1.Refresh()

            'If these columns should be hidden based on the value of the checkbox, you can just use the value of the checkbox. This is a great way to reduce code provided your condition is SIMPLE 
            GridView1.Columns("SUBFOLDERP").Visible = CheckBox1.Checked
            GridView1.Columns("FILENAME1").Visible = Not Checkbox1.Checked
            GridView1.Columns("FILENAME2").Visible = False
            GridView1.Columns("FILENAME3").Visible = False
            GridView1.Columns("FILENAME4").Visible = False
            GridView1.Columns("FILENAME5").Visible = False
            GridView1.Columns("FILENAME6").Visible = False
        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: I've tried your code successfully population to DataGridView but the checkbox doesn't work or it has no effect to the second query . `GridView1.Columns("SUBFOLDERP").Visible = CheckBox1.Checked` and `GridView1.Columns("FILENAME1").Visible = Not Checkbox1.Checked` you mean to code like this

Comment: Those were just examples of alternatives. Do with those booleans as you wish. Are you saying that the check box is not causing the query to change or that it is always marked checked or unchecked?